# Why do languages with such different alphabets use the same common punctuation marks?

Tags: historical-linguistics, writing-systems, punctuation

From my experience, many languages with absolutely different alphabets colloquially use the same common punctuation marks, such as:

- the question mark (?), for inquiring/interrogatives
- exclamation mark (!), for excitement or emphasis
- period (.), for declaration

For example, asking a question in a couple different languages:

- What's your name?
- Как тебя зовут?
- ما اسمك؟
- 您貴姓大名？

Or exclaiming something:

- Cheers!
- За здоровье!
- Στην υγειά σου!
- 乾杯!

How have these stayed in common usage throughout the evolution of languages and their alphabets? Were they standardized at some point?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They were standardized at some point, in the 19th-20th centuries, but many languages still keep their own ancient punctuation, e.g. the [Armenian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_alphabet#Punctuation) period is `:`, the Armenian question mark is `՞` which is put above the last vowel letter of the question word, the Greek question mark is `;`, Spanish uses the upside-down question mark `¿` at the beginning of interrogative sentences (`¿Qué?` 'What?'), the same with the exclamation mark (`¡Hola!` 'Hi!'). [Japanese has specific punctuation](http://www.tofugu.com/2011/12/08/japanese-punctuation/), the period is `。`. Amharic keeps the ancient [Ge'ez punctuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge'ez_script#Punctuation), but it gets outdated now and often substituted with the European-style one. Many Asian scripts of Indian origin, e.g. [Javanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_script#Punctuation), still keep their traditional punctuation.

Comment: Do you have any references about how this standardization took place or what may have driven it?

Comment: @acattle - For every languages it happened at a different time, that's a matter of history of every specific language. Have a look at this: http://www.openculture.com/2013/09/the-history-of-punctuation.html and http://grammar.about.com/od/punctuationandmechanics/a/PunctuationHistory.htm and http://msmcclure.com/?page_id=6448

Comment: That comment is more or less what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @zixuan Please make a greater effort to write grammatically. People have been flagging your comments for the last couple of days because they have no idea what you're trying to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

In Arabic and Chinese the use of Western-style punctuation is very modern, not before the 20th century.